# How to use AngularJS ngroute but animate mouse/touch sliding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have a simple app that uses ngRoute for page navigation. The problem is that I would like to give the user feedback when they drag to change the page (with mouse or touch). I have seen demo code that allows the user to drag back and forth, but it is all is divs and does not use ngRoute ([link](http://www.webdeveasy.com/pages-slider-with-javascript-and-css/)).

Is it possible to stick with ngRoute but also implement dragging (where you see the next page appear while you drag)? How would it be done?

I thought about performing an animate during the drag and then change the $location when the dragging stopped, but maybe there is a more elegant way.

Comment: I was tasked with the same exact solution. This solution is very involved and my team and I eventually scrapped the idea. I suggest just using ng-animate and make a pseudo drag.

Comment: The problem is that I still need to support the regular ngRoute type navigation. So I would basically have to write some code to do that myself. It wouldn't be a huge deal because my app basically works like a configurable slide show, but I'd rather not.